# annotation in eclipse for using google client api from android - @Key

Tags: android, eclipse, google-api-java-client

I am trying to use the google api to access picasa from android.
I'm following a sample that parses atom by doing:

AlbumFeed feed = request.execute().parseAs(AlbumFeed.class);

In order for the atom parser to work I understand that I need to define classes that have a @Key annotation like:

```
  public class Link {

    @Key("@href")
    public String href;

    @Key("@rel")
    public String rel;
  }
```

But eclipse doesn't even compile this - I keep getting both:
Key cannot be resolved as a type
and 
The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Key

I know you can define annotations in eclipse on the project but I thought you needed some processing class.

Any help is greatly appreciated - what are the steps to get eclipse to compile this so I can parse the Atom payload?

Once it compiles, I understand that I need to add
-keepattributes *Annotation*,Signature 
if I use proguard. is that true? any other pitfalls?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the jar file to your Android project.  I am using android-maven-plugin these days, so the only thing I need is adding the following to my pom.xml,

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>
```

@Key is from the class, com.google.api.client.util.Key. You can get the JAR file at http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Download_the_Zipped_Jars.[image]

Comment: thanks barryku. but i already have it. it's an external jar - here's what's in classpath:
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/rbnatan/workspace/GoogleClientAPIs/google-api-client-1.4.1-beta.jar"/>
Is this enough? i.e. is it enough in the buildpath or I need to include it elsewhere?

Comment: I added the JAR to the Factory Path in Annotation Processing - still no dice.

Comment: Here's what I did that worked, 1. added a lib folder and copy the jar to the folder. 2. In java build path of the project properties, added the jar at the "Libraries" tab. I included a screeshot, so hopefully it will be clear.